# Problem with editing Master Page on Sharepoint 2013 Designer

Tags: master-page

I take this error:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: check if you master page is checked out?

Comment: Is there a .html attached to the master?

Comment: Remember to never edit the original master page. Always make a copy of a existing one and edit that one.

Comment: No this page is not check.

Comment: Yes there is a html file

Comment: I try to create copy from Html file, but when I copied to another file with new name, and try to edit it again put the same error

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.